# Error in Apply function: "arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0"

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame.  I need to search for column "a", and if "a" equals "foo", column "b" equals "found"

```
a <- c("foo", "bar", "baz", "foo")
b <- c(0, 0, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

f <- function (x){
  if (x["a"] == "foo"){
    x["b"] <- "confirm"
  }
}

result <- apply(df, 1, f)
```

The intended result is

```
a        b
"foo"    "confirm"
"bar"    0
"baz"    0
"foo"    "confirm"
```

but when I do this, result returns:

```
 [[1]]
[1] "confirm"

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
[1] "confirm"
```

and View(result) gives the error:
    Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Is it adding another dimension to the data frame?

Comment: A function needs to `return(x)` at the end.

Comment: I added `return(x)` but in the result my rows and columns are transposed.

Comment: Yeah, that's a negative side-effect of using `apply`. People usually just `t()` at the end to reverse it or try to avoid using `apply`.

Comment: Thanks, @Frank, the transpose did it for me. And thank you for suggesting the return method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using `ifelse` and the `mutate` command from dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c("foo", "bar", "baz", "foo")
b <- c(0, 0, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

result <- df %>%
    mutate(b = ifelse(a == "foo", "confirm", b))

# a       b
# 1 foo confirm
# 2 bar       0
# 3 baz       0
# 4 foo confirm
```

If you want to write your own function, make sure it has a return statement (as Frank said in his comment).

Answer (score 0):

To use the base package only:

`result <- data.frame(a, b=(ifelse(a=="foo","found",b)))`